# Get application parameters for user

Tags: android, authentication

I need to create Android application that should authenticate user and get several parameters related to that user. I suppose I must:

```
1 Create infrastructure with database that holds table with user id and parameters.   
2 I need to create web service that will have function with input parameter like user_ID and output parameters with application settings. 
3 Create authentication service that will hold all users in it's internal table and will give me user id when authentication is done?
```

Is my understanding of situation is correct? How to organize all this in most simple way?

I have seen user authentication by passing his Google account. I suppose it is most simple way. How to create such feature four my application?

Comment: maybe an easier approach would be to use firebase authenticaion and its SDK https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth